# Best Key-Value System For LaTeX

Tags: macros, pgfkeys, key-value

I want to make new macros that support key=value style.  But, there are many such packages for doing this.

What is the best choice, given these priorities:

1. Highly developed, complete, or actively developed, lots of attention
2. Works well with other packages, fewest conflicts.
3. Available with texlive or Fedora repo
4. Native or core extension preferred over third party package, by which I mean the 'latex' basic/standard compiler.

Comment: Welcome! As it stands, this question is really asking for opinions and that's interesting but not suitable for this format. Could you edit your question to be a bit more specific? Because the truth is, the best choice depends on what you are using it for. I've used all of the ones you mention except `keyreader` and I use another option as well. Horses for courses - asking which horse you'd suggest entering into an arbitrary race isn't a useful question. Which race? A minimal example document which shows what you are trying to do would greatly improve your question and the quality of answers.

Comment: `expl3` and its `l3keys` seems also plausible; and it's going to be the “main future” of LaTeX. In a general case, I would personally choose that, and `pgfkeys` in second place because I like the easiness and flexibility to define new keys.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I found `keyval` and `xkeyval` a nightmare to use in comparison with both `pgfkeys` and, expecially, `l3keys`. I never did get to grips with them and am greatly relieved that `l3keys` and `pgfkeys` have come along so I may never have to. I find `l3keys` by far the easiest for complex stuff and `pgfkeys` by far the easiest for simple stuff. But I would mainly use `pgfkeys` or `l3keys` based on what I was doing - if it is TikZ or something similar, `l3keys` becomes at least a bad dream, and `pgfkeys` makes much more sense. But my kilometres have evidently differed from yours ;).

Comment: @cfr: Yes, we had gone different ways ;-)

Comment: @cfr: I've deleted my comment, since it was apparently not useful, regarding the votes...

Comment: Sorry, yes, I guess I didn't follow the rules.  I'll try to fix it, but...I didn't even know about l3keys and I searched for a while before posting here, so I'm already glad I did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no concept of **best** in the TeX world.

---

As mentioned in the comments, most active key-value handling packages are `pgfkeys` and the `l3keys`. The latter is also inspired by `pgfkeys` however it requires a minimum level of LaTeX3 knowledge which might be a bit baffling for newcomers since it doesn't have a comprehensive introduction and manual (yet!).

`pgfkeys` on the other hand is pretty straightforward and has a very very comprehensive description placed within the graphics package TikZ/PGF manual (hence the name `pgfkeys` which TikZ uses extensively).

Both packages are pretty matured and can handle pretty complicated tasks.

Personally I would suggest starting with `pgfkeys` if compared the two. However, if a minimal L3 knowledge is present they are more or less equivalent in terms learning curve.

---

Even I use `pgfkeys` mostly and extensively, my personal favorite is [`yax`](http://ctan.org/pkg/yax) which is from one of my favorite manual writers Paul Isambert. Yax gives a more Pythonic dictionary-based attribute parameter syntax which is not very common in TeX universe but once you get a hold of it, it really pays off. Though it might not be the most general or the most up-to-date it still gets the job done.

Comment: I think there is an L3 manual now! [Here it is](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf). For reference, take a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/633551/64441).