# Latest user-level manuals for LaTeX 3 (follow up to Ivo Welch)

Tags: latex3, documentation

This is not a duplicate but a follow up spurred on by Ivo Welch's question [Is there a LaTeX 3 transition guide for users (not gurus)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633473) where he asked if there was a LaTeX 3 transition guide for users.

On StackExchange I have noticed that a number of answers included code related to `Hooks` and to strange ways of describing the options and arguments of a new macro. One answer to Ivo noted the `usrguide3` document. Following this up I found that the `interface3` and `lthooks` manuals were noted. I have managed to `texdoc` these but to me they don't give an integrated user-level manual for what one can now do in LaTeX.

As a past software developer I am aware that the first priority is to document what you have done (it really helps if later you can't quite remember the why and how). A later priority is to explain to the potential users how to take advantage of your magnificent work.

I have a strong feeling that documentation can take even more time than the original work but it is very important.

I appreciate all the hard work that has gone into the current documentation but I hope that soon some comprehensive user-level manual can be developed that explains and highlights what one can do in the current LaTeX environment --- at least a concatenation  of `usrguide3`, `interfaces3` and `lthooks` documents targeted at users, not necessarily at package writers.

Comment: [Alan Xiang](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/219915/alan-xiang) has written a [LaTeX 3 tutorial](https://www.alanshawn.com/latex3-tutorial/) which also helps you getting used to interface3.pdf.

Comment: @Peter usrguide3 aims as users, but interface3 is the reference manual of the L3 programming layer and is not aimed at users. It is complete, ie covers every public function of the L3 programming layer, it is what was always missing for LaTeX2e (you had to look into the source code there, ie source2e to find out what \@whiledo was doing etc -- for L3 programming layer there is a similar code documentation called source3).  lthooks is the odd one because it some of it should go into usrguide3 but the rest into  a programming guide for "higher-level". And there should be a programming cookbook

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I found `usrguide3` and`lthooks` very useful; `interface3` is comprehensive but too much for my purposes. Perhaps my fault is keeping my LaTeX current  but not reading the manuals of new/updated packages that are used in some of the SE MWEs answers. Any chance of `tlmgr` suggesting reading the manuals of new LaTeX code downloads? I know that some package code is incorporated into LaTeX base, other packages are used regularly, and others fade into the background.

Comment: There is also the short overview `texdoc expl3`, "an introduction to the ideas behind the expl3 programming interface" - 15pp.

Comment: @Cicada Thank you for noting `expl3`. I have received much useful information from you and others.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LaTeX3 (L3 Programming Layer) interfaces like `\cs_new_protected:Npn` are mainly for package writers and advanced users. And LaTeX2 interfaces like `\NewDocumentCommand` are for normal users.

For advanced users (I would define them as users who have some knowledge about macro expansions of TeX), [`interface3`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) is a comprehensive and excellent manual to read, and in my opinion is more or less enough.

For normal users, since currently only a small part of LaTeX3 provides LaTeX2 interfaces, there are not many manuals to read:

- [`xparse`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf): for `\NewDocumentCommand`, `\NewDocumentEnvironment`, etc.
- [`xfp`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xfp.pdf): for `\inteval` and `\fpeval`.
- [`lthooks`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/lthooks-doc.pdf), [`ltcmdhooks`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltcmdhooks-doc.pdf), [`ltfilehook`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltfilehook-doc.pdf): for `\AddToHook`, `\RemoveFromHook`, etc.

Even an integer stepping function `\int_step_inline` in LaTeX3 has not yet provided a LaTeX2 interface, so for normal users I would suggest to use other existing package such as `pgffor` and be patient to wait.

PS: See also a related issue I opened [here](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/769) some days ago.

---

**Update on 2022-03-19**: I have written a new [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package based on LaTeX3 Programming Layer (`expl3`). This package provides easy-to-use LaTeX2 interfaces for `expl3` which emulates functional programming in other programming languages such as `Lua` or `JavaScript`. And the manual of this package includes more examples than `interface3`. I think this package would be handy for many normal users.

Answer (score 2):

FYI

With a (very quick) prototype tutorial-like experimental tryout like this:

[image: quick demo]

(it highlights what the tokens are)

I would estimate, via a proverbial back-of-the-imaginary-envelope calculation, a ~400 hr effort (for me: no touch-typing, etc). Something more-or-less the size of a medium-length novel (in 12 pt) in terms of word-count.

Luckily, expl3 is consistently and logically structured.

Expl3-coders: An "atom" layer (how each command works, + commentary, exercises), a "scenario" layer (solving real use-cases), and perhaps the proverbial cookbook (projects, etc).

User-transition guides should be minimal, I expect, since expl3 would be the internals of the user-command they would be using.

Coincidentally, there have been a slew of expl3 questions over the last week or so.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}% also loads xparse
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\testfont{Noto Serif}
%\tracingxpatches

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}


\DeclareTCBListing{mybox}{ s O{} m }{%
colback=red!3!white,
colframe=red!75!blue,
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
bicolor,
colbacklower=yellow!20,
segmentation style={double=white,draw=blue,
double distance=1pt,solid},
listing options={style=tcblatex,numbers=left,numberstyle=\small\color{blue!75!black},numbersep=5pt},%IfBooleanTF={#1}
%{listing side text}
%{text side listing},
title=\getegcounter\ -- #3,#2}



\ExplSyntaxOn

%\int_new:N \ic_eg_count
%\newcounter{egcounter}[section]
\newcounter{ic_eg_count}[section]
%\newcommand\getegcounter{\refstepcounter{egcounter}[\thesection.\theegcounter]}


\cs_new:Nn \ic_get_egnum: {
%\refstepcounter{egcounter}[\thesection.\theegcounter]
\refstepcounter{ic_eg_count}[\thesection.\theic_eg_count]
}

\cs_set_eq:NN \getegcounter \ic_get_egnum:


\int_new:N \g_commcount_int
\NewDocumentCommand { \comm } {  } {
    \textsc{Commentary:} ~
    \int_gset:Nn \g_commcount_int { 0 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \cc } {  } {
    \par\noindent
    ( \int_gincr:N \g_commcount_int
    {
        \sffamily
        \int_use:N \g_commcount_int
        }
    ) ~
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \nocomm } {  } {
    -- ~
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \res } {  } {
    \par\textsc{Result:} ~
}



%\newcommand{\dobb}[1]{\renewcommand\ProcessedArgument{\fbox{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{#1}}}}}


\cs_new:Npn \ic_do_bluebold: #1  {
\renewcommand\ProcessedArgument{\fbox{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{#1}}}}
%\cs_gset:Nn \ic_processed_arg:n { \fbox{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{#1}}} }
%\exp_args:NNo \cs_gset_eq:NN \ProcessedArgument \ic_processed_arg:n
}


\NewDocumentCommand { \dca } { s o >{\ic_do_bluebold:}m v } {
    #4 ~ : ~ 
    \IfBooleanTF {#1} {star} {no star}
    ;~ \IfNoValueTF {#2} {no opt = #2} {OArg = #2}
    ;~ MArg = #3.
%   \par \#3 ~ after ~ pre-processing = #3
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { codeillus } { +b } {
    \begin{quotation}
    \marginpar{\getegcounter}
    \ttfamily
    #1
    \end{quotation}
}{}

%\newcommand\icmarker{ \% <------}
\cs_new:Nn \ic_marker: {  \% ~ <------ }
\tl_new:N \l_ic_parm_tl
\NewDocumentCommand { \vv } { m O{\ic_marker:} } {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_ic_parm_tl { #1 }
    {
    \bfseries
    \color{blue}
%  \detokenize { #1 }
  \tl_to_str:N \l_ic_parm_tl
    } ~~~ #2
}

\ExplSyntaxOff




\begin{document}

\section{Basics}

%===================== 
\begin{codeillus}
\vv{\ExplSyntaxOn}

Some code.

Some code.

Some code.

\vv{\ExplSyntaxOff}

\end{codeillus}


%===================== 
\begin{codeillus}
Some code.

\vv{\group_begin:}

Some code.

\vv{\group_end:}

Some code.
\end{codeillus}



%===================== 
\begin{mybox}{Grouping}
\ExplSyntaxOn
Text ~ text ~
\group_begin:
\color{red}
\large
text ~ text ~
\group_end:
text ~ text.
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{mybox}
\bigskip




%===================== 
\begin{mybox}{Defining a function}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \ic_funca:n #1 { {\color{blue} \bfseries #1 } }

Text ~ \ic_funca:n { ~ This ~ is ~ blue ~ bold. } ~ Text.
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{mybox}
\bigskip



%===================== 
\begin{mybox}{Defining a user command}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \mycmdb } { m } {
\cs_new:Npn \ic_funcb:n ##1 { {\color{blue} \bfseries ##1 } }
 \ic_funcb:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
Text \mycmdb{This is blue bold.} Text.
\end{mybox}
\bigskip


%===================== 
\begin{mybox}{Using a token list}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_myicc_tl
\NewDocumentCommand { \mycmdc } { m } {
\tl_set:Nn \l_myicc_tl { #1 }
\cs_new:Npn \ic_funcc:N ##1 { {\color{blue} \bfseries ##1 } }
 \ic_funcc:N \l_myicc_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
Text \mycmdc{This is blue bold.} Text.
\end{mybox}
\bigskip



%===================== 
\begin{mybox}{Appending to a token list}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_myicd_tl
\NewDocumentCommand { \mycmdd } { m } {
\tl_set:Nn \l_myicd_tl { #1 }
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_myicd_tl { $\leftarrow$ ! ! }
\tl_put_left:Nn \l_myicd_tl { ! ! $\rightarrow$ }
\cs_new:Npn \ic_funcd:N ##1 { {\color{blue} \bfseries ##1 } }
 \ic_funcd:N \l_myicd_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
Text \mycmdd{This is blue bold.} Text.
\end{mybox}
\bigskip


%===================== 
\begin{mybox}{Modifying a token list (\texttt{\textbackslash tl\_replace})} 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_myice_tl
\NewDocumentCommand { \mycmde } { m } {
\tl_set:Nn \l_myice_tl { #1 }
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myice_tl { blue } { not ~ red }
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myice_tl { bold } { italic }
\cs_new:Npn \ic_funce:N ##1 { {\color{blue} \bfseries ##1 } }
 \ic_funce:N \l_myice_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
Text \mycmde{This is blue bold.} Text.
\end{mybox}
\bigskip

%===================== 
\begin{mybox}{Modifying a token list (\texttt{\textbackslash regex\_replace})} 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_myicez_tl
\NewDocumentCommand { \mycmdez } { m } {
\tl_set:Nn \l_myicez_tl { #1 }
\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ (\c{color} \cB\{ [^\cE\}]* \cE\}) } 
{ not \  } 
\l_myicez_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ \c{textbf}(.+)(bold) } 
{ is\ \c{textsc}\1 small\ caps } 
\l_myicez_tl
\tl_use:N \l_myicez_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
Text \mycmdez{This is {\color{blue}blue} and \textbf{bold}.} Text.
\end{mybox}
\bigskip




%===================== 
\begin{mybox}{Copying a control sequence}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \ic_funcf:N #1 { {\color{blue} \bfseries #1 } }
\cs_new_eq:NN \mybbcmd \ic_funcf:N
\ExplSyntaxOff
Text \mybbcmd{This is blue bold.} Text.
\end{mybox}
\bigskip




%===================== 
\begin{mybox}{Looping}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \ic_funcg:n #1 { \symbol{#1} }
\cs_set:Nn \ic_funcgb:  {
\int_step_function:nnnN { 97 } { 1 } { 122 } \ic_funcg:n
\ 
}
\cs_new_eq:NN \myloopcmd \ic_funcgb:
\ExplSyntaxOff
Text \myloopcmd Text.
\end{mybox}
\bigskip

\comm
\cc Open the expl3 environment.
\cc Define a 1-parameter function, g, that will print a glyph, given the glyph's slot number, in the current font using the symbol command.
\cc Define a no-parameter function, gb, that will
\cc step through values 97 to 122 (inclusive) and pass each value to the g function.
\cc Add a space (replacing the one gobbled after the command in the user code).
\cc \nocomm
\cc Create a user-command, \textbackslash myloopcmd, that will call the gb function.
\cc Close the expl3 environment.
\cc Use the user-command
\res The letters a..z are printed, followed by a space.
%\begin{quotation}
%>>\myloopcmd<<
%\end{quotation}



%===================== 
\begin{mybox}{Mapping function}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \ic_funch:n #1 { \fbox{#1}. }
\tl_new:N \l_myich_tl
\NewDocumentCommand { \mycmdh } { m } {
\tl_set:Nn \l_myich_tl { #1 }
\tl_map_function:NN \l_myich_tl \ic_funch:n
\par tl ~ = ~ >> \tl_use:N \l_myich_tl << 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
Text \mycmdh{abc{de}fgh} Text.
\end{mybox}
\bigskip


%===================== 
\begin{mybox}{Mapping inline function}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \ic_funci:n #1 { \fbox{#1}. }
\tl_new:N \l_myici_tl
\NewDocumentCommand { \mycmdi } { m } {
\tl_set:Nn \l_myici_tl { #1 }
\tl_map_inline:Nn \l_myici_tl { \ic_funci:n {##1} }
\par tl ~ = ~ >> \tl_use:N \l_myici_tl << 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
Text \mycmdi{abc{de}fgh} Text.
\end{mybox}
\bigskip


%===================== 
\begin{mybox}{Contents of a token list (1)}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_myicj_tl
\NewDocumentCommand { \mycmdj } { m } {
\tl_set:Nn \l_myicj_tl { #1 }
\par (a) ~ \tl_count:N \l_myicj_tl  \ token ~ groups.
\par (b) ~ \tl_count_tokens:n { \l_myicj_tl } ~ token \int_compare:nNnTF {\tl_count_tokens:n { \l_myicj_tl }} = { 1 } { } { s }.
\par (c) ~ \exp_args:No \tl_count_tokens:n { \l_myicj_tl } ~ tokens: ~
{ \color{blue} \tl_to_str:N \l_myicj_tl }.
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\mycmdj{abc{de}fgh}
\end{mybox}
\bigskip




%===================== 
\begin{mybox}{Contents of a token list (2)}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_myick_tl
\NewDocumentCommand { \mycmdk } { m } {
\tl_set:Nn \l_myick_tl { #1 }
\par head: ~ \tl_head:N \l_myick_tl  
\par tail: ~ \tl_tail:N \l_myick_tl  
\par reverse: ~ \tl_reverse:N \l_myick_tl   \tl_use:N \l_myick_tl ~<~ \tl_to_str:N \l_myick_tl
\par 5th ~ item : ~ \tl_item:Nn \l_myick_tl { 5 }
\par reverse: ~ \tl_reverse:N \l_myick_tl   \tl_use:N \l_myick_tl ~<~ \tl_to_str:N \l_myick_tl
\par reverse ~ items: ~ \exp_args:No \tl_reverse_items:n { \l_myick_tl } ~<~ \tl_to_str:N \l_myick_tl
\par 5th ~ item : ~ \tl_item:Nn \l_myick_tl { 5 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\mycmdk{abc{de}fgh}
\end{mybox}
\bigskip





%===================== 
\begin{mybox}{Tokens}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_myiclz_tl
\cs_set:Npn \ic_funcl:n #1 { 
\tl_set:Nn \l_myiclz_tl { #1 }
\fbox{ \strut \tl_to_str:N \l_myiclz_tl } $^ \exp_args:No \tl_count_tokens:n { \l_myiclz_tl }$
\int_compare:nNnT 
{ \exp_args:No \tl_count_tokens:n { \l_myiclz_tl } }
> 
{ 1 }
 { >> \mycmdl{#1} << }
}
\tl_new:N \l_myicl_tl
\NewDocumentCommand { \mycmdl } { m } {
\tl_set:Nn \l_myicl_tl { #1 }
\tl_map_function:NN \l_myicl_tl \ic_funcl:n
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
 \mycmdl{abc{d\textit{e}}fgh}
\end{mybox}
\bigskip

%\tl_item:Nn






*=====



\section{regexpatch}


\begin{mybox}{testca}
\newcommand{\testca}{\textit{label}}
Before: \testca
\par \regexpatchcmd{\testca}{\c{textit}}{\c{textbf}}{S}{F}
\par \xpatchcmd{\testca}{label}{babble}{S}{F}
\par After: \testca
\end{mybox}
\bigskip


%\xshowcmd*\ph
%\makeatletter
%\makeatother

%\tracingxpatches
\begin{mybox}{ph: Too many brace levels}
\newcommand{\ph}[1]{
\textbf{\textsc{{\color{blue}#1}}}\ \ }
Before: {\testfont\ph{Snail in the Bottle}}
\regexpatchcmd{\ph}{\c{color}\cB\{blue\cE\}}{red}{}{F}
\par After: {\testfont\ph{Snail in the Bottle}}
\end{mybox}
\bigskip

\tracingxpatches[0]
\begin{mybox}{ph2: Two levels of braces}
\newcommand{\phb}[1]{\textsc{{\color{blue}#1}}\ \ }
Before: {\testfont\phb{Snail in the Bottle}}
\regexpatchcmd{\phb}{\c{color}\cB\{blue\cE\}}{red}{}{F}
\par After: {\testfont\phb{Snail in the Bottle}}
\end{mybox}
\bigskip

\begin{mybox}{ph3: Entire \textbackslash color command replaced}
\newcommand{\phc}[1]{{
\bfseries\scshape\color{blue}#1\ \ }}
Before: {\testfont\phc{Snail in the Bottle}}
\regexpatchcmd{\phc}{\c{color}\cB\{blue\cE\}} {\c{color}\cB\{red\cE\}}{}{F}
\par After: {\testfont\phc{Snail in the Bottle}}
\end{mybox}
\bigskip

\begin{mybox}{ph4: Text replaced: `blue' > `red'}
\newcommand{\phd}[1]{{
\bfseries\scshape\color{blue}#1\ \ }}
Before: {\testfont\phd{Snail in the Bottle}}
\xpatchcmd{\phd}{blue}{red}{}{F}
\par After: {\testfont\phd{Snail in the Bottle}}
\end{mybox}
\bigskip



\begin{mybox}{ph5: Text (`blue') replaced by a macro (`\textbackslash mycolour')}
\newcommand{\mycolour}{green}
\newcommand{\phe}[1]{{
\bfseries\scshape\color{blue}#1\ \ }}
Before: {\testfont\phe{Snail in the Bottle}}
\regexpatchcmd{\phe}{blue}{\c{mycolour}}{}{F}
\par After: {\testfont\phe{Snail in the Bottle}}
\end{mybox}
\bigskip


\begin{mybox}{ph6: Multi-level grouping without braces\footnote{\sffamily\color{blue!5} ``patchable'' = it can be reconstructed from its decomposition under the current category code egime. -- Manual, \S 7.1 (2018/05/02)}} 
\newcommand{\mycolour}{brown}
\newcommand{\phf}[1]{\begingroup
\bfseries\begingroup\scshape\begingroup\color{blue}#1\endgroup\ smallcaps\endgroup \ bold\endgroup\ normal \ \ }
Before: {\testfont\phf{Snail in the Bottle}}
\regexpatchcmd{\phf}{blue}{\c{mycolour}}{}{F}
\par After: {\testfont\phf{Snail in the Bottle}}
\end{mybox}
\bigskip

\dca{x}{\dca{x}}

\dca*{y}{\dca*{y}}

\dca[abc]{z}{\dca[abc]{z}}

\dca[xyz]{zz}{\dca[xyz]{zz}}

\dca*[xyzz]{zzz}{\dca*[xyzz]{zzz}}


\begin{mybox}{ph4a: Text replaced: `blue' > `red'}
\newcommand{\phda}[2]{{
\bfseries\scshape\color{blue}#1\normalcolor\ in the \color{blue}#2}}
Before: {\testfont\phda{Snail}{Bottle}}
\xpatchcmd{\phda}{blue}{red}{}{F}
\par After: {\testfont\phda{Snail}{Bottle}}
\end{mybox}
\bigskip

\begin{mybox}{ph4b: Text replaced: all `blue' > `red'}
\newcommand{\phdb}[2]{{
\bfseries\scshape\color{blue}#1\normalcolor\ in the \color{blue}#2}}
Before: {\testfont\phdb{Snail}{Bottle}}
\xpatchcmd*{\phdb}{blue}{red}{}{F}
\par After: {\testfont\phdb{Snail}{Bottle}}
\end{mybox}
\bigskip





\end{document}
```

Comment: For those interested in tracking this, I've set up a github repo: https://github.com/texcicada/expl3